# Passing data between ViewControllers using prepareForSegue not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsurl

so I am basically building a small browser. On one VC you'd put in the link into a textField and use a button to segue to the other VC where the webView is found.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewOne:UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func clear(sender: AnyObject) {
    textField.text = ""
    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "go" {
            let controller:ViewTwo = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewTwo
            controller.textField = self.textField.text! as String
        }
    }
}


import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewTwo:UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    let url = NSURL(string: textField!)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if let urlContent = data {
            let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
                self.webView.loadHTMLString(String(webContent!), baseURL: nil)
            })
        }
    }

    task.resume()

    if textField?.isEmpty == true {
        print("nothing received")
    } else {
        print("\(textField)")
    }

}

var textField:String?
}
```

It seems like the data won't pass. I get a fatal error saying the NSURLSession found nothing while unwrapping "url".

Comment: Post code as code, not an image

Comment: Have you checked whether the segue identifier in your code matches with the one in your Storyboard?

Comment: **1.)** Are you actually setting the textField's text within the app before segueing, or just leaving it blank?  **2.)** Try moving your `textField.isEmpty` conditional to a `viewDidLoad()` function, and handling the potential nil value there.  **3.)** As requested by @Wain, please post actual code instead of images.

Comment: @ZGski but I thought the viewDidLoad function only works once at the beginning? That is why I am using viewDidAppear. I'm sorry for that. I've changed to code already. Of course I'm inputting a URL!

Comment: You are correct in that the `viewDidLoad()` will be called only when the ViewController is instantiated, so you may be fine with keeping the conditional within your `viewDidAppear()`. However, it's generally a good idea to check and handle for a nil passed value before using using it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `NSURL(string: "\(XXX)")` because the description of the string will include that it's optional. Instead just use the string `NSURL(string: textField!)`.

Comment: Thanks, now it is working, but for some reason it isn't working for http://www.google.com, but http://www.youtube.com works. Arbitrary loads have been enabled in the info.plist file...

Comment: you need to debug the URL, session response, string from data, web view errors...

Comment: I'm sorry but what does that mean exactly? This error never happened to me before. Why would youtube work, but google not?

Comment: i don't have enough information to guess, you need to check what's happening when you run it and this information will provide understanding (or at least the ability to guess)

Comment: what gives you nil? anything with `Optional` in it means it's a description of something...